# BI tool redash cannot parse unicode chinese

Tags: python-unicode, redash

I want to query a column in [Redash](https://redash.io/) with SQL, but it does not support Chinese. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

```
SELECT user_history.id, user_history.user_id AS `汉字id`
FROM data_platform.user_history
WHERE dt = {{ dt}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting of `汉字id` was not correct. Below query will work on an MySQL database, but not necessarily with Google BigQuery.

```
SELECT user_history.id, user_history.user_id AS '汉字id'
FROM data_platform.user_history
WHERE dt = {{ dt}}
```

Comment: @zuoli: Please don't forget to vote the answer up if you found it helpful :)